# how to get last time stamp value:mysql

Tags: mysql

```
price             create date
==========        ===================
1201.39978        2014-12-16 06:58:38
1201.39978        2014-12-16 07:00:14
1201.39978        2014-12-16 07:00:38
1266.99982        2015-01-29 07:45:13
1265.9            2015-01-29 07:47:13
1264.99986        2015-02-29 07:49:13
1264.19988        2015-02-29 07:51:13
1262.69976        2015-03-29 07:53:13
1263.99989        2015-04-29 07:55:13
1263.69974        2015-04-29 07:57:13
```

how to get lastprice of the date based on timestamp..?
please help me

Comment: Just use `order by create date` and  `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: it is difficult to answer like this, do you mean, for each day, get the last price? pls edit your question adding your desired output

Comment: you have invalid data in your data sample :-) `2015-02-29` doesn't exist in real world calendar :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT price, 
       created 
FROM   (SELECT Max(created) AS maxts 
        FROM   table_name 
        GROUP  BY Date(created)) AS m 
       INNER JOIN table_name t 
         ON m.maxts = t.created;
```

results here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3104/3

Comment: Thank you so much the above link is use full me

Comment: @9030355963 You are welcome; if you found the answer useful, consider accepting it by pressing the check-mark on the left, or up-voting it by clicking the up arrow. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44b64/1

```
SELECT p.*
FROM prices p
LEFT JOIN prices p1
ON p.create_date < p1.create_date
  AND DATE(p.create_date) = DATE(p1.create_date)
WHERE p1.create_date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select price from yourtablename orderby create_at asc limit 1;
```